# Preventing Terraform from assigning reserved IP addresses to resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code

I have a scenario where I’m using AWS server setup with an EFS and RDS setup. To enable high availability, I’ve configured a PCS cluster, and as a result, some IP addresses have been reserved as virtual IPs.

For deployment, I’m using a Terraform script. However, I’ve noticed that sometimes during deployments, Terraform automatically assigns these reserved IPs to some resources.

To illustrate, in this setup, the app servers are in a private subnet, and the RDS is also in this private subnet. Sometimes, Terraform assigns one of the IPs, which are reserved for app servers as Virtual IPs, to the RDS.

I want to prevent Terraform from assigning these reserved IPs to any other resource during deployment. What are the best practices or solutions to achieve this in Terraform?

Comment: Terraform is just calling the AWS API to create a resource in your VPC. It is the AWS VPC that is then assigning an available IP address to the resource that is created. Perhaps you should describe how you have "reserved" these IP addresses, because it sounds like you haven't actually reserved them in the VPC.